# How can I do ConfigureAwait(false) synchronously

Tags: async-await

I have Asnyc method and I do the following

```cs
await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This works fine. But apart from the forementioned Async method, I also have a Synchronous counter part as well. This methhod does not return Task and is not 'async'. So if I have to execute the above line of code in a Synchronous method, how would that be?

### Update

Ok, I past the full method here.

```cs
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
  var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // ignore events if no dispatcher provided
  if (_mediator == null) return result;

  // dispatch events only if save was successful
  var baseEntitieList = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType?.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseEntity<>))
    .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList();

  foreach (var baseEntity in baseEntitieList)
  {
    var eventsField = baseEntity.GetType().GetField(nameof(BaseEntity<int>.Events));
    var listOfDomainEvents = (List<BaseDomainEvent>)eventsField!.GetValue(baseEntity)!;
    if (listOfDomainEvents.Any())
    {
      foreach (var domainEvent in listOfDomainEvents)
      {
        await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent).ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
    }
  }
    
  return result;
}
```

And now the Sync counter part I am talking about. Note this is not async method and does not return **Task of int**, but rather returns just int.

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
  var result = SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  // ignore events if no dispatcher provided
  if (_mediator == null) return result;

  // dispatch events only if save was successful
  var baseEntitieList = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType?.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseEntity<>))
    .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList();

  foreach (var baseEntity in baseEntitieList)
  {
    var eventsField = baseEntity.GetType().GetField(nameof(BaseEntity<int>.Events));
    var listOfDomainEvents = (List<BaseDomainEvent>)eventsField!.GetValue(baseEntity)!;
    if (listOfDomainEvents.Any())
    {
      foreach (var domainEvent in listOfDomainEvents)
      {
        // I am not sure the following is the correct way to execute in sync(not async)

       // Shoud I use the below? I got this idea from the line above, the 3rd line in this code block. 
       // var result = SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       _mediator.Publish(domainEvent).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

       // Or should I use the below as you suggested.
       _mediator.Publish(domainEvent).Wait();
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. `ConfigureAwait` has no meaning without `await`. As for `I also have a Synchronous counter part as well.` what does that mean? That you have eg a `PublishAndWait()` method? There's no async operation to return from in this case. Your method is already running on the main thread (and blocking it)

Comment: Are you asking how to execute a blocking operation in the background? `await Task.Run(()=>thatOperation())`

Comment: Please take a look at my update

Comment: That code is a huge problem. Why even write this `SaveChanges` method if all it does is call and *block* asynchronous methods? Why not call the synchronous methods instead? Never mind - why write the sync version? Second, you're tightly coupling different systems at exactly the wrong level. EF Core is an ORM, its job is to map objects to database tables. It's a *subscriber* to business change events, not a publisher of change events.

Comment: Because it is provided by [Entity Framework core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-6.0). I am just overriding it.

Comment: The problem is the overriding code. It integrates different services at the wrong level *and* uses the wrong methods. And the way it's written it will even store and send the same changes twice, because ` SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` calls the *first* version

Comment: Instead of `SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` use `base.SaveChanges();`. You're overriding the *synchronous* method, so why call the *async* version? Retrieving the changes is the same in both versions so should be extracted in a separate method called by both versions. Publishing to MediatR should be a *separate* step executed *after* retrieving the changes.  At this point the only difference between the two methods would be calling `await _mediator.Publish()` or `_mediator.Publish().Wait()`.

Comment: Ok, My dumbness, Now I understood. Thanks. That means, I dont need any other except for **SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ** Thanks once again.